# My outlook add-in does not count the keyword I enter in the search bar

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

So, I have been creating an outlook add-in in c# that reads the email attachments(PDF, Doc/Docx) and searches for keywords I enter in the search bar from the attachments. but the problem is I can find those emails with the email attachments but it does not give me the count right. I think the reason this is happening is that I can't properly retrieve the words from the attachment. Any help will be appreciated Thank you!

Here's what it is so far:

[image: Entering keyword into search bar]

[image: Searched for keyword, but does not show proper count (should be 1)]

^Should output 1

EDIT: Added code that I am using that gives unexpected results

```
private int countKeywords(Outlook.Attachment attachment, string keyword)
    {
        const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

        var attachmentData = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN);
        //MessageBox.Show(TextFromWord(attachment));
        string data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(attachmentData);

        int i = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;
        if (data.Contains(" "))
        {

            while (i < data.Length)
            {
                if (data[i] == ' ' && data.Substring(startIndex, i - startIndex).Equals(keyword))
                {
                    startIndex = i + 1;
                    count++;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (data.Equals(keyword))
                count++;
        }

        //  MessageBox.Show(Encoding.GetString(attachmentData));
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a programming question? What is the relevant snippet of your code that produces unexpected results?

Comment: Yes, just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do you really have UTF-16 encoded data in the attachment? Or is it single byte? Use ASCII encoding instead of Unicode.

Secondly, keep in mind that OOM won't let you access large (32kB+) binary properties using PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. You will need to save the attachment as a file (Attachment.SaveAsFile) or use other means of getting the attachment data without saving it (Extended MAPI or Redemption).

Have you tried to step through your code and inspect the values of the variables to make sure you get the data you expect?